# Can I use a Silverlight WCF RIA with WinForms?

Tags: winforms, silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I'd like to make ONE WCF Service hosted on a server for every platform I'm going to develop for. Like if I make one Silverlight application, I'd like to be able to use the same WCF as if I'd make a WinForms application.

Is it possible? I'm kind of new to the whole WCF world, I'm using it at work but I'm not the one who setup'd it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have written and deployed your RIA service to a server, it's a web service.  Accordingly, it can be accessed by anything or anybody who can reach the service.  If it's deployed in a DMZ for example, anybody in the world who clears authentication on that server can access your RIA service.  Hence the advice from security gurus to make your RIA services agnostic.

So the answer to your question is yes, of course a WinForms app can use it.  If you have trouble getting the WinForms app configured, you can use the 'Fiddler' utility to tweak and tune your app.

Comment: Oh alright! I was just unsure about the whole class usages thing. If let's say my WCF has a User class and I want to use it in my app. Will I have to make my own User class when I'll get some object from the WCF? For the moment the WCF is in the same solution so I can access them well, but what when I'll separate them? Thanks!